# Is there a special tag I can add to my page to describe the content to web crawlers?

Tags: html, web-crawlers, google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools

My page is based on `HTML` and I need to submit it to Google Webmaster Tools and  To Bing.

I know how to give short description about my page.  So that it easy to crawl my page, there is lots of HTML code and a description tag:

```
<meta name="description" content=""/>`
```

Is that enough or do I need to add still more special tags for crawlers?  I ask because Google says **can't find content in your page still add more content to your page**.

Answer (score 1):

Google is looking for content on your page, predominantly words. If you don't have information (a paragraph or two, descriptions of images, a collection of links to specific subjects) on your webpage then the search engine robots don't know how to interpret what they are "seeing".  Including a [robots.txt file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) in your primary directory will help Google etal know which areas of your website to/not to include.

Answer (score 0):

This tool will help you generate meta tags for your site
http://tools.seobook.com/meta-medic/

Though, do you actually have any content on your site or is it a blank page?

You might want to consider adding content( images, paragraphs... etc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to be found on the web? Make use of [Google Webmasters tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/). Sign in to https://www.google.com/webmasters/ It will offer you with tools to help increase your site ranking.

In there, you can submit your site and provide link to your sitemap. The required `meta` will be generated for you to embed into your site header.

Goodluck!

Comment: already completed brother but still unable to find my site

Comment: @romman Setting up an account with Google Webmasters Tool and submitting your website only sets you up to be found and indexed by Google. Your site still needs to meet some other guidelines if Google must rank it in the first page of its search result.  Follow this guideline https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Once you have submitted your site to Google via Webmaster Tools, you should see it starting to get indexed. It also helps to make use of all the tools in there,like the ones under "Search Appearance".

It takes time for your site to be crawled and start showing up in searches.